# Submit data via form to database and see result + edit data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that allows me to submit data directly to the database without any problems. My form is too basic and when I submit data, it lets me know a record has been submitted but I would like to extend the form with an option to click a button to post new data but also see the records that I have posted.

I also need to secure the php page via a login.

Server is running 4.3 php and everything is working fine.

Submit Form

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_name">Fullname</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="company">PayPal Transaction ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="serial_no">Serial Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="serial_no" id="serial_no">
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

File that submits the data

```php
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_name']);
$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$serial_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['serial_no']);

$sql="INSERT INTO clients2 (user_name, company, email, serial_no)
VALUES ('$user_name', '$company', '$email', '$serial_no')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
exec("php index.php")
?>
```

The output result is to be able to see the results of the database and be able to edit them without having to log into the database and do it manually. Option to post new data after submitting data.

Admin login screen to prevent anyone from seeing the form data.

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add PHP condition in you HTML form like this

```
<input type="text" <?php if(isset($_POST['user_name'])) echo "value=".$_POST['user_name'])  ?> name="user_name" id="user_name">
```

an obviously use escaping function for the security